# Php ftp_get gives obscure warning

Tags: php, ftp, runtime-error, warnings

I'm currently using ftp_get to try and retrieve files in a directory and transfer them to a copy locally.  As it goes along it works fine for the first few files but then starts returning Warning messages like:

`Warning: ftp_get(): 20130827142004 in /myfile.php on line 160`

My Code is as follows:

```
$ftpConnection = ftp_connect( $this->getHost() );
if ( false === $ftpConnection ) {
    throw new \Exception( "Failed to connect to the host {$this->host}" );
}

$ftpLogin = ftp_login( $ftpConnection, $this->getUsername(), $this->getPassword() );
if ( false === $ftpLogin ) {
    throw new \Exception( "Failed to login using the provided credentials" );
}

// Tried with and without pasv turned on
ftp_pasv( $ftpConnection, true );
$fileModTime   = ftp_mdtm( $ftpConnection, $origin ); // returns -1 for the files that fail ftp_get
ftp_get( $ftpConnection, $dest, $origin, FTP_BINARY );
ftp_close( $ftpConnection );
```

I have no idea what the random integer error means or whats different about these files.  They seem to be the same size as all the previous files that succeeded.

Comment: looks like a timestamp: 2013/08/27 14:20:04

Comment: You're right it is a timestamp.  Seems to be when the file was last modified.  Not sure why it would spit that out as a warning though.  I've tried file_get_contents to retrieve the failing image and that works, but not ftp_get.

Comment: Can you capture the FTP session with Wireshark?